# EF CodeFirst CTP5 with Repository and UnitOfWork: System.InvalidOperationException (...not part of... ...current context...)

Tags: .net, ef-code-first

I'm testing the EF CodeFirst CTP5 and was trying to implement The Unit Of Work and Repository patterns. But when I run a simple test I get:

*System.InvalidOperationException : The entity type Log is not part of the model for the current context.*

The Database get's created by the EF and it fails when I call .Add()
It seems that the same context is not being used but I can't figure out why?

Hoping for some smart human coming to rescue me!
Thanks in advance for taking your time.

Here is some code:

LogCabinContext

```
public class LogCabinContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public LogCabinContext() { }

    public LogCabinContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {

    }

    #region IUnitOfWork Members

    public void Save()
    {
        base.SaveChanges();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

BaseRepository

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : EntityBase
{
    public LogCabinContext _unitOfWork;
    private DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public BaseRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        if (unitOfWork == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("UnitOfWork must not be null");

        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork as LogCabinContext;
        _dbSet = _unitOfWork.Set<T>();
    }

    #region IBaseRepository Members

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return _dbSet.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> List()
    {
        return _dbSet.OrderBy(x => x.Id).AsEnumerable();
    }

    public IUnitOfWork CurrentUnitOfWork
    {
        get { return _unitOfWork; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _unitOfWork.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

SimpleTest, using Ninject to build the context, this works since I creates the DB

```
[TestFixture]
public class LogRepositoryTests
{
    IKernel _kernel;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _kernel = new StandardKernel(new DatabaseModule());
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _kernel.Dispose();
    }

   public ILogRepository GetLogRepository()
   {
        ILogRepository logRepo = _kernel.Get<ILogRepository>();

        return logRepo;
   }

   [Test]
   public void Test()
   {
        using (ILogRepository repo = this.GetLogRepository())
        {
           Log myLog = new Log();
           myLog.Application = "Test";
           myLog.Date = DateTime.Now;
           myLog.Exception = "Exception message";
           myLog.Machinename = "local";
           myLog.Message = "Testing";
           myLog.Stacktrace = "Stacktrace";

           repo.Add(myLog);
        }
   }
}
```

ILogRepository, just derives from base for now

```
public interface ILogRepository : IBaseRepository<Log>
{
}
```

Comment: I am getting a similar exception in my application. Have you found the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Answered here: [Entity Framework 4 CTP 4 / CTP 5 Generic Repository Pattern and Unit Testable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442828/entity-framework-4-ctp-4-ctp-5-generic-repository-pattern-and-unit-testable/4458250#4458250)