# WCF Data Services and EF 4 CTP 5 POCO - Unable to cast Unable to cast object of type '...DbQuery' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`

Tags: entity-framework-4, poco, odata, wcf-data-services

I got this error message while querying the top 50 row in a table. My project uses Entity Framework 4 CTP 5 POCO:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Lib.Model.Post]'
```

My Models was based on this answer: [Entity Framework 4 CTP 4 / CTP 5 Generic Repository Pattern and Unit Testable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442828/entity-framework-4-ctp-4-ctp-5-generic-repository-pattern-and-unit-testable)

Any idea on how to fix this error?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide more context. As it stands, I can play the amazing kreskin and attempt to devine all the possibilities. What is the code surrounding the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing the DataService context and override the ObjectContext, the service is now working. Here's what I've changed in case anyone also run into the same problem:

```
public class KennyService : DataService<MyDataContext>
{
    // Codes
}
```

to

```
public class KennyService : DataService<System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext>
{
    // Codes
}

protected override ObjectContext CreateDataSource()
{
    var context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)new Lib.MyDataContext()).ObjectContext;
    context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    return context;
}
```