# Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-ctp5

I get this error on this line of code -

```
    ReportRunnerEntities reportDB = new ReportRunnerEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        **var types = reportDB.ReportTypes.ToList();**
        return View(types);
    }
```

The tables in the databse have primary keys defined and identities set.

My models are -

```
namespace ReportRunner.Models
{
    public partial class ReportRunnerEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Reports> Report { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ReportTypes> ReportTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace ReportRunner.Models
{
    public partial class ReportTypes
    {
        public int ReportTypeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Reports> Reports { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace ReportRunner.Models
{
    public class Reports
    {
        public int ReportId { get; set; } 
        public int ReportTypeId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; } 
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public ReportTypes ReportType { get; set; }
    }
```

}

```
namespace ReportRunner.Models
{
    public partial class Users
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; } //ArtistId
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is my connection string -

I suspect that it's never reaching the database. As I said the keys are set in the database.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please post the error you are getting.

Comment: And where do you say EF that ReportTypeId, ReportId and UserId are primary keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things I see that should change:

- ReportTypes should be ReportType
- public List Reports { get;
  set; } should be public
  ICollection Reports { get;
  set; }
- If you are defining a
  connection string in your web.config,
  you need to tell EF what one it is
  using the constructor in your
  ReportRunnerEntities class like this:

  ---

  ```
  namespace ReportRunner.Models
  {
      public partial class ReportRunnerEntities : DbContext
      {
          public ReportRunnerEntities : base("name=NameOfConnectionInWebConfig")
          {}
          public DbSet<Reports> Report { get; set; }
          public DbSet<ReportTypes> ReportTypes { get; set; }
          public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
      }
  }
  ```

You can read more on that here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-2-connections-and-models.aspx

Just on a side note, if you are planning on using .NET MVC and EF Code First as your stack, I would start using the Repository and Unit of Work pattern. Here is a good post on how to set that up: [Entity Framework 4 CTP 4 / CTP 5 Generic Repository Pattern and Unit Testable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442828/entity-framework-4-ctp-4-ctp-5-generic-repository-pattern-and-unit-testable/4458250#4458250)