# Entity Framework CTP5 Repository + Unit of Work for winform

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-ctp5, ef-code-first

I want to build a windosform application using Repository and Unit of Work pattern.
Most of existing sample use ObjectContext but I use DbContext.
How can I do this?

Comment: It is the same. You just use `DbContext` instead of `ObjectContext`, `DbSet` instead of `ObjectSet`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for web, but could be altered quite easily for win forms: [Entity Framework 4 CTP 4 / CTP 5 Generic Repository Pattern and Unit Testable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442828/entity-framework-4-ctp-4-ctp-5-generic-repository-pattern-and-unit-testable/4458250#4458250)