# Cannot insert record using EF 4 CTP5 repository pattern

Tags: entity-framework, entity, repository-pattern

I'm using the repository pattern explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442828/entity-framework-4-ctp-4-ctp-5-generic-repository-pattern-and-unit-testable/4458250#4458250), in a Console application (just to get the feeling of how it works) and is seems i make some fundamental error.

I'm using Unity to initialize the IoC like this:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
            container
                .RegisterType<Abstract.IUnitOfWork, Concrete.UnitOfWork>()
                .RegisterType<Abstract.IDatabaseFactory, Concrete.DatabaseFactory>( );
```

I noticed that the DatabaseFactory returns always a Database which is in a disconnected state..is that right? (I 'm focusing on using this later in a WPF application!)

I'm sure i'm missing something....

Comment: Does it work without using DI/IoC?

Comment: What do you mean by disconnected state?

Comment: @Paul, @Ladislav Sorry for replying that late...was kind of ill!! See my answser

Answer (score 0):

The IoC initialization was almost correct! The problem i got was due to the fact that i had wrongly defined a one-to-one relation. This caused insertion problems!

So i guess this matter is closed now!