# Entity Framework: POCO and encapsulation of IQueryable code

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

The question is about convenient code organization.

I've moved my POCO classes to the persistence independent project.  Should I move IQueryable code (part of "business rules" around those POCOs, used for example to generate derived non-persistent business object) together or better to leave all IQueryable code in the library with ObjectContext?

Comment: That is completely up to you.

Comment: That means that persistence independent library can contain IQueryable expressions which are "not executable/testable" without persistence layer ... This speculation somehow string up my nerves.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051145/using-the-repository-pattern-to-support-multiple-providers/6051328#6051328 Exposing `IQueryable` will not break ability to test your code but you will have to use integration tests instead of unit test. Check also links in that answer. I wrote some ideas about this perhaps you will find some useful information there.

Comment: Thank you, Ladislav. If I get all information right your advice is "don't forget about leaky abstraction , but try don't latch it"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment, you say, "That means that persistence independent library can contain IQueryable expressions which are "not executable/testable" without persistence layer...". That's not true. You can test IQueryable expressions in a (mostly) persistence-independent manner.

E.g.:

```
public IQueryable<Foo> SomeFoos(IQueryable<Foo> foos, string aValue)
{
    return from foo in foos 
           where foo.Bar = aValue
           select foo;
}
```

You can use this with L2E:

```
var f = SomeFoos(myContext, "Baz");
```

You can test it with L2O:

```
var expected = new Foo { Bar = "Baz" };
var notExpected = new Foo { Bar = "Oops" };
var input = new [] { expected, notExpected };

var actual = instance.SomeFoos(input.AsQueryable(), "Baz");

Assert.AreEqual(actual.First(), expected, "Should have found expected record.");
Assert.AreNotEqual(actual.Single(), notExpected, "Should not have found unexpected record.");
```

This is a made-up example, but hopefully the point is clear: How you structure this really is up to you, as @Ladislav states.

Comment: Yes, you are right: it is possible to execute IQueryable expression just on the "ad hoc" lists. 

To finalize: it is possible to keep declarations of SomeFoos and Foo class together (in one project), no contradictions in that.

Comment: You need to pass `input.AsQueryable()` into `SomeFoos` in the LTO example, don't you?