# Unit testing asp.net mvc4 with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

The Web request 'Url to Test' completed successfully without running the test.

This error can be passed by not calling the asp server; commenting out the lines between TestMethod and CreateTest. but then i get the following error?

System.ArgumentException: The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.

The App config file in the test project has no connections. I tried inserting the relavant connection strings and 
I also copied into the project the web.config from the main project, But i still get this error?!
I have researched some threads which indicate i half to use some sort of a fake database? Is this true; if so could someone point me

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [HostType("ASP.NET")]
    [AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\CA3 EAD\\CA3 EAD", "/")]
    [UrlToTest("http://localhost:2124/")]
    public void CreateTest()
    {
        EmployeeController target = new EmployeeController(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        Employee employee = new Employee(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        //employee.Name = "test";
        //employee.Surname = "test";
        //employee.Town = "test"; ;
        //employee.County = "test";
        //employee.Country = "test";
        //employee.GradeID = 4;
        //ActionResult expected = target.Create(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        //ActionResult actual = null;
        var expected = target.Create();
        var actual = target.Create(employee);
        //Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        //Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
    }
```

Comment: You're actually performing an _integration test_, since you are testing more than one _unit_. If you want a true _unit test_ of your controllers, you should mock any data access.

Comment: I previously had an issue with tesing ef attached to a forms project, got a similar error which i resolved by copying the app.config into the test project. So are you saying mvc4 does not allow such an approach, i have to use mog or rhino in this case?

Comment: No, you don't have to mock. Personally, I would write integration tests like you have in addition to mocking with unit tests. That said, copying relevant portions of web.config to your test projects app.config _should_ fix your issue.

Comment: I resolved my unit testing issue for the time been. the app config file in the test project was bare so i copied all the connection strings from web.config; However if i only copy the one i needed, the test works !

Answer (score 0):

This has plagued my for a long time and is quite a controversial issue.

[Fake DbContext of Entity Framework 4.1 to Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904139/fake-dbcontext-of-entity-framework-4-1-to-test)

See answers such as the above.