# How to create ObjectQuery for testing EF4 'Include' method

Tags: entity-framework-4, typemock-isolator

We are using EF4 and creating test cases for DAL layer (DAL layer is having linq query). We are using TypeMock as mocking framework. For testing, we are creating Fakecontext of `ObjectContext` and mocking `CreateObjectSet` method as follows:

```
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeContext.Context.CreateObjectSet<User>)).WillReturnCollectionValuesOf(fakeUsers.AsQueryable());
```

The above is working fine. The issue is when we are trying to include related tables using 'Include'. We have extended the include method as follows:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T>> property)
{ 
    var objectQuery = source as ObjectQuery<T>; 

    if (objectQuery != null) 
    { 
        var propertyPath = GetPropertyPath(property); 
        return objectQuery.Include(propertyPath); 
    } 

    return source; 
}
```

So what happen is, in the above `Include` method the source type should be `ObjectQuery<T>`. But as we have mocked `CreateObjectSet`, source type in `Include` method is of `Collection.Generic.List` type. Kindly let us know how should we mock in the above case. Your timely help will be highly appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Can you format at least one your question correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Include associated entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104461/how-to-include-associated-entities)

Answer (score 0):

[Object Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386871.aspx) can be difficult to use when writing unit test. Unfortunately, there is not a good interface to mock for `ObjectQuery<T>` as you have found out. To handle this scenario I have created a wrapper class following the Repository pattern to encapsulate my `ObjectContext` and created a wrapper class to encapsulate `ObjectQuery<T>`:

```
public interface IMyObjectQuery<T> : IOrderedQueryable<T>
{
    IMyObjectQuery<T> Include(string path);
}

public class MyObjectQuery<T> : IMyObjectQuery<T>
{
    private ObjectQuery<T> _query;

    public MyObjectQuery(ObjectQuery<T> query)
    {
        _query = query;
    }

    IMyObjectQuery<T> Include(string path)
    {
        //There is probably a better way to do this
        //but you get the idea
        return new MyObjectQuery(_query.Include(path));
    }

    //Implement IQueryable, IEnumerable...
}
```

And then it is a matter of implementing a Repository wrapper for your ObjectContext. [Here](http://coderjournal.com/2010/11/entity-framework-repository-pattern/) is a link to get you started.

Add something like this:

```
public class MyRepository : IMyRespository
{
    ...
    public IMyObjectQuery<T> CreateQuery<T>()
    {
        return new MyObjectQuery(_context.CreateQuery<T>());
    }
    ...
}
```

This is probably not the simple solution that you were looking for, as it is not a trivial task. I think you will find that if you don't you will continue to encounter difficulty writing tests.