# EF 4.1 Code First doesn't initialize DB (DropCreateDatabaseAlways) when using Moq

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, moq, code-first

I'm using Entity Frameworc 4.1 Code First and [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/). And I want to test database initializer. Also I have the abstract BaseUnitOfWork class which inherited from DbContext (so, for testing it should be mocked).

```
public abstract class BaseUnitOfWork : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    ...
        public IDbSet<User> Users
        {
            get
            {
                return Set<User>();
            }
        }
    ...
}
```

User is simple POCO with three properties: Id, Login, Password.

And here is the code of the DbInitializer:

```
public class BaseDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BaseUnitOfWork>
{
    protected override void Seed(BaseUnitOfWork context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);

        context.Set<User>().Add(new User { Login = "admin", Password = "1" });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to test this initializer with the next test (NUnit is used):

```
[TestFixture]
public class BaseDbInitializerTests
{
    private BaseUnitOfWork _baseUnitOfWork;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new BaseDbInitializer());
        _baseUnitOfWork = new Mock<BaseUnitOfWork>(Consts.ConnectionStringName).Object;
        _baseUnitOfWork.Database.Initialize(true);
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void CleanUp()
    {
        _baseUnitOfWork.Dispose();
        Database.Delete(Consts.ConnectionStringName);
    }

    [Test]
    public void ShouldInitializeBaseDb()
    {
        var repository = new Mock<BaseRepository<User>>(_baseUnitOfWork).Object;

        var firstUserInDb = repository.FindBy(x => x.Login == "admin" && x.Password == "1").SingleOrDefault();

        Assert.That(firstUserInDb, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(firstUserInDb.Login, Is.EqualTo("admin"));
        Assert.That(firstUserInDb.Password, Is.EqualTo("1"));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it seems like Seed method of the BaseDbInitializer class doesn't execute. DB is recreating, but there is no any records, and I tried to debug this test and Seed method was executed during debug session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strategy `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BaseUnitOfWork>` is looking for an exact type match of `BaseUnitOfWork`, not a derived type, and not `Mock<BaseUnitOfWork>`. If you need it, you'll have to implement a copy of the strategy for the mocked type.

Comment: Does DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges use the same strategy?

Answer (score 1):

What is the point of mocking context and in the same time expecting database to exists? The point of mocking is removing dependency on the database (but it [will not always work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766478/unit-testing-dbcontext)).

So either use mock (unit test with [all its problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904139/fake-dbcontext-of-entity-framework-4-1-to-test/6904479#6904479)) or database with real context and integration test.

Comment: The point of mocking is because BaseUnitOfWork is abstract class. so I'm mocking only it.

Comment: But in such case you are throwing away database access so you don't need to create any database.

Comment: yes, that right, that was mainly theoretical question then practical