# How do I create an abstract class from DbQuery<T> and IDbSet<T> on EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework

is that possible create an abstract class from DbQuery and IDbSet? I'm trying to create an abstraction layer for my unit testing.

```
public abstract class BaseDbSet<T> : DbQuery<T>, IDbSet<T> where T : Entity
{
    #region IDbSet<T> Members

    public abstract T Add(T entity);
    public abstract T Attach(T entity);
    public abstract TDerivedEntity Create<TDerivedEntity>() where TDerivedEntity : class, T;
    public abstract T Create();
    public abstract T Find(params object[] keyValues);
    public abstract ObservableCollection<T> Local { get; }
    public abstract T Remove(T entity);

    #endregion
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Error 1   The type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery'
>   has no constructors
>   defined   @path\BaseDbSet.cs

If I try to add a constructor I get:

> Error 1   The type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery'
>   has no constructors
>   defined   @path\BaseDbSet.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the constructors are declared as internal. Hence you can not access them.

Unit testing EF code is a flawed concept. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766478/unit-testing-dbcontext/6768712#6768712). You are wasting valuable time on unnecessary abstractions.