# Mock ForeignKey column is not working as per expectation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, testing, mocking

My entities are like below:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Class2 Class2{ get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Class1")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Price { get; set; }
    public virtual Class1 Class1{ get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following test that I expected to be failed but it is passed:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateClass2()
{
    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Class2>>();

    var mockContext = new Mock<theContext>();
    mockContext.Setup(m => m.Class2s).Returns(mockSet.Object);

    var service = new Class2Service(mockContext.Object);
    service.AddClass2(10, 100);

    mockSet.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Class2>()), Times.Once());
    mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());
}
```

And this is the `service.AddClass2` method:

```
public class Class2Service
{
    private readonly theContext _context;

    public CoordService(theContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public Class2 AddClass2(int id, int? price)
    {
        var class2 = _context.Class2s.Add(new Class2 { Id = id, Price = price });
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return class2;
    }
}
```

Since I have not added a `Class1` yet and entered an invalid `id` for `Class2` (i.e it is not exist in `Class1`), the new entry for `Class2` should be invalid since I have constrained it with foreign key. **In my project and real database it works as expected and gives me error, but in this test it is passed!**

Comment: I think your ForeignKey("Class1") should be ForeignKey("Class1Id")

Comment: @Steve this `ForeignKey` behavior is working as expected in my database and real adding Class2, it just not working in the test.

Answer (score 0):

The test uses mock context instead of a real one, so  `_context.SaveChanges();` will actually do nothing, so no exception is thrown.

You can easily google on how to mock a `DbContext` properly, e.g. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx)  or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960192/mocking-ef-dbcontext-with-moq?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Also I think the unit test itself should be written in a different way. I.e. you are testing the method calls here, which is the underlying implementation of adding a record.

A proper unit test for this case would check if the `service.AddClass2(10, 100);` call throws exception. And a separate test should be written to see if a new record appears in the DbSet as a result of `service.AddClass2` method call instead of checking that some particular methods were called.

UPD: an example of setting an `IQueryable` as a source for a fake context.

```
    public static class MockDbSetExtensions
{
    public static void SetSource<T>(this Mock<DbSet<T>> mockSet, IList<T> source) where T : class
    {
        var data = source.AsQueryable();
        var iQuryableSet = mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>();

        iQuryableSet.SetupGet(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        iQuryableSet.SetupGet(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        iQuryableSet.SetupGet(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        iQuryableSet.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());
    }
}
```

And sample usage:

```
    [TestClass]
public class GigRepositoryTests
{

    private GigRepository _repository;
    private Mock<DbSet<Gig>> _mockGigs;
    private Mock<IApplicationDbContext> mockContext;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        _mockGigs = new Mock<DbSet<Gig>>();

        mockContext = new Mock<IApplicationDbContext>();


        _repository = new GigRepository(mockContext.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetUpcomingGigsByArtist_GigsInThePast_ShouldNotBeReturned()
    {
        var gig = new Gig() {DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), ArtistId = "1"};

        _mockGigs.SetSource(new List<Gig> {gig});
        mockContext.SetupGet(c => c.Gigs).Returns(_mockGigs.Object);

        var gigs = _repository.GetUpcomingGigs("1");

        gigs.Should().BeEmpty();
    } }
```

Comment: I have exactly used this reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx as you linked, but I don't know how should I mock a DbContext property? Also theContext that is used in this test is used the `Class2s` that is the real one used in my original DbContext.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how can I Mock ForeignKey column  behavior?

Comment: I have updated my question that shows I'm using the real context.

Comment: You are still not testing the real context, because you pass a fake one through the constructor of the service here: `     var service = new Class2Service(mockContext.Object);`

Actually it looks like an impossible and useless thing to test the foreign key behavior because it is actually a DB's business. Please check out this answer to a pretty similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904139/fake-dbcontext-of-entity-framework-4-1-to-test/6904479#6904479

Comment: So what should I do? Can you please append the solution in your answer? I'm really confused since I'm really new to Mocking

Comment: Still, if you'd like to test the AddClass2 method you could set an IQueriable as a source for the DataContext or use the real database.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So can you please give me an example of how can I apply IQueriable with my example? If I set IQueriable with this fake context is foreignkey work?

Comment: I have provided a sample in the original answer. The foreign key will not work in this case.

Comment: Oh, It seems to be very complicated than I imagine! How can I use this complex example with my simple requirement?

Comment: You add MockDbSetExtensions class first.Then you create a new List<Class2> which will be used as a source and call SetSource on your mock DbSet passing this list _before_ setting up the context. Will be smth like:

`
var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Class2>>();
var list = new List<Class2>();
mockSet .SetSource(list);
mockContext.Setup(m => m.Class2s).Returns(mockSet.Object);
`