# C# Moq how to setup EF DbContext extension method ToList() to return mock.Object.Tolist()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, moq, mstest

I'm trying to mock Entity Frameworks DbContext using Moq and in particular its extension methods Add(), Tolist() and Find().

I need the Find() and ToList() methods to **actually return values** stored in my `mockContext.Object`.

I've created my DbSet and set following properties:

```
var mockTickets = new Mock<DbSet<Ticket>>();

mockTickets.As<IQueryable<Ticket>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(tickets.Provider);
mockTickets.As<IQueryable<Ticket>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(tickets.Expression);
mockTickets.As<IQueryable<Ticket>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(tickets.ElementType);
mockTickets.As<IQueryable<Ticket>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => tickets.GetEnumerator());
```

I've created my DbContext with the following property

```
var mockContext = new Mock<SupportCenterDbContext>();
mockContext.Setup(m => m.Tickets).Returns(mockTickets.Object);
```

Now I'm trying to test the following methods

- `mockContext.Object.Tickets.Add(Ticket ticket)`
  returns Ticket t
- `mockContext.Object.Tickets.ToList<Ticket>()`
  returns IEnumerable tickets
- `mockContext.Object.Tickets.Find(int ticketNumber)`
  returns Ticket t

I've tried the following code but get "Invalid setup on an extension method".

```
mockContext.Setup(x => x.Tickets.Add(It.IsAny<Ticket>())).Returns(It.IsAny<Ticket>());
mockContext.Setup(x => x.Tickets.ToList()).Returns(mockTickets.Object.ToList());
mockContext.Setup(x => x.Tickets.Find(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(It.IsAny<Ticket>());
```

These are my assertions for the `Add()` and `ToList()` methods

```
//ToList
Assert.AreEqual(result.Count(), mockContext.Object.Tickets.Count());
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(IEnumerable<Ticket>));

//Add
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(Ticket));
mockContext.Verify(x => x.Tickets.Add(It.IsAny<Ticket>()), Times.Once());
mockContext.Verify(x => x.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());
```

**EDIT**
I'm a step closer by removing `mockContext.Setup(x => x.Tickets.ToList()).Returns(mockTickets.Object.ToList());`.

and adding the following

- `mockContext.Setup(x => x.Tickets.Add(It.IsAny<Ticket>())).Returns<Ticket>(x => x);`
- `mockContext.Setup(t => t.Tickets.Find(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns<int>(x => mockContext.Object.Tickets.Find(x));`

This last line still doesn't produce the desired output. Is it not possible to pass the value of the input parameter to the `Find()` method in the `Returns()` section?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you can mock extension methods. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295960/mocking-extension-methods-with-moq) mock dbcontext [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960192/mocking-ef-dbcontext-with-moq)

Answer (score 2):

You can't mock extension methods, and it is not a common practice to mock the DBContext.

A better idea would be to use an in-memory data context and populate it with test data, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory

Comment: I agree. Or if you don't like the inmemory approach, the typical alternative is to let your application logic not directly tap into DBContext, but though Repositories (this enforces cleaner design anyway) and let those repositories use the DBContext. Then, unit test the app logic by mocking the simple Repositories, and write integration tests on an actual DB for your repositories.

Comment: @Thomas my app does use repositories, I've left this out for the sake of less code and a more direct approach to the issue. My `TicketRepository` has a private DBContext which is initialized in the constructor. I've implemented an overload to allow the DBContext to be injected via the constructor. Are you suggesting I mock `TicketRepository` instead of mocking DBContext and injecting it into `TicketRepository`?

Comment: @X3ntr if you want to test the business logic, then yes, mocking the repositories is the way to go

Comment: @MelGerats I'm looking to test my repository's functionality, so technically this would be DAL and not BL

Comment: The repos are tested with an actual instance of dbcontext with an actual db behind it, no mocking, integration testing. Downsides: having the actual db as a test dependency & its slower than inmem db testing. Upsides: your repos are tested against the same db tech as used in production & you avoid mocking dbcontext. Summarized: you have an annoying design problem that cannot be solved in an ideal manner. So, move that lesser design to one place and keep the rest of your design clean.