# Writing a unit test for a Builder Class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing a project that takes a JSON file to deserialize it and Build the data and process them  then save it to the database. Now I want to write a unit test using Mock for this class but I don't know how to do this because in this method I only equalize the field in my DTO and database

this is my order Dto

```
  public class OrderDto
  {
            public int Code { get; set; }
            public int CustomerCode { get; set; }
            public int StoreCode { get; set; }
            public string OrderDate { get; set; }
            public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
            public string DeliveryDate { get; set; }

  }
```

This is my order builder class

```
 public class OrderBuilder
  {
      static PracticeEntities _context;

      public OrderBuilder(PracticeEntities4 context)
      {
          _context = context;
      }
        public static CustomersOrder OrderBuild(OrderDto dto)
        {
            //using (var context = new PracticeEntities4())
            //{
                var oldStoreId = _context.Stores.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Code == dto.StoreCode).Id;
                var oldCustomerId = _context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Code == dto.CustomerCode).Id;
                return new CustomersOrder()
                {
                    OrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dto.OrderDate),
                    OrderStatus = dto.OrderStatus,
                    DeliveryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dto.DeliveryDate),
                    CustomerId = oldCustomerId,
                    StoreId = oldStoreId,
                    Code = dto.Code
                };
            //};
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

First thing to note is that a static class can't be unit tested. So the method to be tested shall be modified as such below shown. Also, the dbcontext i.e. `IPracticeEntities4` interface which is implemented in the `PracticeEntities4` class need to be injected so that it can be mocked.

```
 public class PracticeEntities4:IPracticeEntities4, DbContext
 {
  ....
 } 

public class ClassMethod2BTested
{  
   IPracticeEntities4 _context; //declare the context
   public ClassMethod2BTested(IPracticeEntities4 context) // inject the context
   {
      _context=context; // set the context to local variable
   }
   public CustomersOrder OrderBuild(OrderDto dto)
   {
        //using (var context = new PracticeEntities4()) // remove this
        {
            var oldStoreId = _context.Stores.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Code == dto.StoreCode).Id;
            var oldCustomerId = _context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Code dto.CustomerCode).Id;
            return new CustomersOrder()
            {
                OrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dto.OrderDate),
                OrderStatus = dto.OrderStatus,
                DeliveryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dto.DeliveryDate),
                CustomerId = oldCustomerId,
                StoreId = oldStoreId,
                Code = dto.Code
            };
        };
    }
}
```

Now the above method can be united tested.

For unit test, Please check the sample here: [Mocking EF DbContext with Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960192/mocking-ef-dbcontext-with-moq)

**Added**

Please check this code:
[github](https://github.com/AJEETX/react.webapi.demo/blob/master/test/Services/ProductServiceTest.cs)

Comment: _First thing to note is that a static class can't be unit tested_ - it can be tested.

Comment: thank you I changed my code now how can I write a unit test?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using entity framework, I think this article will help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking

> Create your own test doubles – This approach involves writing your own in-memory implementation of your context and DbSets. This gives you a lot of control over how the classes behave but can involve writing and owning a reasonable amount of code.
>
> Use a mocking framework to create test doubles – Using a mocking framework (such as Moq) you can have the in-memory implementations of your context and sets created dynamically at runtime for you.

So with the first way you can simulate a db call with specific data and make sure the result returns successfully.

These tests,  while not securing business errors protect your code from missing null checks and runtime errors like that.