# Generic Select clause in Linq

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, generics, entity-framework-4

I have seen generic repository pattern [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149272/ef4-how-to-use-a-generic-repository-pattern). I am trying to add generic select clause that i want to send as argument from calling function. I modified

```
public T GetSingle(Expression<Func<filter, bool>> filter) to 
public T GetSingle(Expression<Func<filter, bool>> filter,Expression<Func<T, T>> Selct)
```

Now I want to call this method. How should i send my select expression

```
return rep.GetSingle(p => p.Slug == slug,???)
```

Comment: We don't know what you're trying to achieve, which makes it rather tricky to know what argument you want to pass. Are you sure you really want an `Expression<Func<T, T>>` rather than the ability to change the result type? (`Expression<Func<T, TResult>>`)

Comment: Actually i want to send a field name from repository and my query should return that field rather than the whole object

Comment: You want to pass in the field name as a *string*, or in a lambda expression? (Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question so we don't need to keep going back and forth.)

Comment: `Expression<Func<T,T>>` would take T as input and return T as output without giving you ability to select specific properties from T.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your method can't change the result type. I suspect that's not what you want. I would expect you'd want your method to be generic, e.g.

```
public TResult GetSingle<TResult>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter,
                                  Expression<Func<T, TResult>> projection)
```

You'd then call that with something like this:

```
// The type argument is inferred from the second lambda expression
string x = repository.GetSingle(p => p.Slug == slug, p => p.FirstName);
```

Comment: and you can also use it like `repository.GetSingle(p=>p.Slug == slug, p=>new{p.FirstName, p.SecondName})`.

Comment: It is giving me error on TResult. saying type or namespace not found

Comment: @Tassadaque: Are you sure you copied my change to the method signature correctly? `TResult` is a generic type parameter *of the method*. (As it happens, I'd got the return type of the method wrong, but that wouldn't explain the error you saw.) And yes, you can call it for an anonymous type.

Answer (score 0):

Your second argument in the method must be another lambda where the input is a T and it must return a T.