# How to insert/update a row using EF?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, insert-update

What is the correct way to insert/update a row using Entity Framework?

I know this 3 methods:

1 - using `Attach`

```
var newSale = _context.ST_Sales.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SaleId == saleId);
newSale.Hours = 2;
_context.ST_Sales.Attach(newSale);
_context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(newSale, EntityState.Modified);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

2 - using `ApplyCurrentValues`

```
var newSale = _context.ST_Sales.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SaleId == saleId);
newSale.Hours = 2;
_context.ST_Sales.ApplyCurrentValues(newSale);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

3 - using `EF logic`

```
var newSale = _context.ST_Sales.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SaleId == saleId);
newSale.Hours = 2;
_context.SaveChanges(); // EF tracks the newSale obj and knows that was changed
```

And to insert there are one more method witch uses the `AddObject`

```
var newSale = new ST_Sales();
newSale.Hours = 2;
_context.ST_Sales.AddObject(newSale);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

**The problem I'm facing** is an error on the EF saying that the modified row is still in memory.

*My scenario:*

- 20 users can add sales to their own company.

I have a simple table relation:

```
tbl_Companies { CompanyId, Name }
tbl_Sales     { CompanyId, Hours, Amount }
```

my `Edit View` simple get's a `sales collection` of the current week as

```
var model = _context.ST_Sales.Where(x => x.CompanyId == 2);
return View(model);
```

and on the `HttpPost` Action I simply loop through each one and save the db changes like

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Index(List<ST_Sales> model)
```

and

```
bool newSale = false;
foreach( var s in model ) { // let's loop through all

    newSale = false;

    var sale = _context.ST_Sales.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SaleId == s.SaleId);
    if( sale == null) {

        // sale was not found, let's add it (this happens for todays date
        //    as there is no info yet in the db, but we need to add today's info)

        sale = new ST_Sale();
        sale.Company.Id = currentLoggedInUser.companyId;

        newSale = true;  // let's say it's a new sale so we can add the new object to the changes to commit
    }

    sale.Hours = s.Hours;
    sale.Amount = s.Amount;

    if( newSale ) {
        // it's a new sale, let's add the obj to our Entity
        _context.ST_Sales.AddObject(sale);
    } 
    else {
        // no need to do anything, EF is tracking the changes of existing objects
    }
}

_context.SaveChanges();
```

This works fine for one user... but if I logout and login with a different user, and I can see in the breakpoint that the `companyId` value is different, soon I commit the changes to be saved I get the weird error:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

**What am I doing wrong?**

---

I'm creating a new instance in the Controller level like:

```
public class SalesController : Controller
{
    private SalesTrackerRepository db = SalesTrackerRepository.Instance;

    ...
}
```

and using the source from [Sams Code](http://samscode.com/index.php/2009/12/making-entity-framework-v1-work-part-1-datacontext-lifetime-management/)

---

Also, I used [Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Feb/05/Linq-to-SQL-DataContext-Lifetime-Management) code and ending up using:

```
public class SalesController : Controller
{
    private SalesTrackerRepository db = 
            SalesTrackerRepositoryFactory.GetWebRequestScopedDataContext<SalesTrackerRepository>();

    ....

}
```

And I keep getting the same error :(

---

**My tests** are based in the same machine using Chrome and Opera with both different credentials.

> How can I get this error on such test?

Comment: How are you creating a new instance of your context?

Comment: added... my Context is always a new one, I just don't get why I'm getting this error with diff contexts :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got the bugger!**

I was using `MemoryCache` to cache some results and realized that I was using that cache to request an `EntityKey`.

**My advise**: Please check if in your project you really want to deal with all this workarounds!

Answer (score 0):

Your `_context` should be created and freed for each request, *no longer.* Multiple, concurrent requests should not share a context.

Comment: I tried, I keep getting the same error :( I'm using this example: http://samscode.com/index.php/2009/12/making-entity-framework-v1-work-part-1-datacontext-lifetime-management/

Answer (score 0):

I would trying using the IDatabaseFactory from this post : [Entity Framework 4 CTP 4 / CTP 5 Generic Repository Pattern and Unit Testable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442828/entity-framework-4-ctp-4-ctp-5-generic-repository-pattern-and-unit-testable/4458250#4458250) along with an IoC Container (Structuremap, Unity, Ninject) to scope the the instantiation of the DatabaseFactory once per Http Request.

**Code should look something like this:**

**IDatabaseFactory.cs**

```
public interface IDatabaseFactory : IDisposable
    {
        Database Get();
    }
```

**DatabaseFactory.cs**

```
public class DatabaseFactory : Disposable, IDatabaseFactory {
        private Database _database;
        public Database Get() {
            return _database ?? (_database = new Database());
        }
        protected override void DisposeCore() {
            if (_database != null)
                _database.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Disposable extension method:

**Disposable.cs**

```
public class Disposable : IDisposable
    {
        private bool isDisposed;

        ~Disposable()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if(!isDisposed && disposing)
            {
                DisposeCore();
            }

            isDisposed = true;
        }

        protected virtual void DisposeCore()
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: The example you specify is using Code First style, I already have my DB in place, I already have my Entities and Repository.